# Maximal mutually co-prime factorization

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, division

## Definitions

- Two numbers are **co-prime** if their only positive common divisor is `1`.
- A list of numbers is **mutually co-prime** if every pair of numbers within that list are co-prime with each other.
- A factorization of number `n` is a list of numbers whose product is `n`.

## Task

Given a positive number `n`, output the mutually co-prime factorization of `n` with the maximum length that does not include `1`.

## Example

For `n=60`, the answer is `[3,4,5]`, because `3*4*5=60` and no other mutually co-prime factorization without `1` has length greater than or equal to `3`, the length of the factorization.

## Rules and freedoms

- You can use any reasonable input/output format.
- The entries in the output list do not need to be sorted.

## Testcases

```
n   output
1   []
2   [2]
3   [3]
4   [4]
5   [5]
6   [2, 3]
7   [7]
8   [8]
9   [9]
10  [2, 5]
11  [11]
12  [3, 4]
13  [13]
14  [2, 7]
15  [3, 5]
16  [16]
17  [17]
18  [2, 9]
19  [19]
20  [4, 5]
21  [3, 7]
22  [2, 11]
23  [23]
24  [3, 8]
25  [25]
26  [2, 13]
27  [27]
28  [4, 7]
29  [29]
30  [2, 3, 5]
31  [31]
32  [32]
33  [3, 11]
34  [2, 17]
35  [5, 7]
36  [4, 9]
37  [37]
38  [2, 19]
39  [3, 13]
40  [5, 8]
41  [41]
42  [2, 3, 7]
43  [43]
44  [4, 11]
45  [5, 9]
46  [2, 23]
47  [47]
48  [3, 16]
49  [49]
50  [2, 25]
51  [3, 17]
52  [4, 13]
53  [53]
54  [2, 27]
55  [5, 11]
56  [7, 8]
57  [3, 19]
58  [2, 29]
59  [59]
60  [3, 4, 5]
61  [61]
62  [2, 31]
63  [7, 9]
64  [64]
65  [5, 13]
66  [2, 3, 11]
67  [67]
68  [4, 17]
69  [3, 23]
70  [2, 5, 7]
71  [71]
72  [8, 9]
73  [73]
74  [2, 37]
75  [3, 25]
76  [4, 19]
77  [7, 11]
78  [2, 3, 13]
79  [79]
80  [5, 16]
81  [81]
82  [2, 41]
83  [83]
84  [3, 4, 7]
85  [5, 17]
86  [2, 43]
87  [3, 29]
88  [8, 11]
89  [89]
90  [2, 5, 9]
91  [7, 13]
92  [4, 23]
93  [3, 31]
94  [2, 47]
95  [5, 19]
96  [3, 32]
97  [97]
98  [2, 49]
99  [9, 11]
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [OEIS for the length of the output.](https://oeis.org/A001221)

Comment: [OEIS for the flattened sequence.](https://oeis.org/A141809) (With a leading `1`.)

Comment: Harder follow-up challenge: only adjacent pairs in the resulting list need to be co-prime.

Comment: @MartinEnder you can post that yourself.

Comment: Is this just a factorization into prime powers?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann yes, it is.

Answer (score 10):

### [Mathics](http://mathics.github.io/), 24 bytes

```
#^#2&@@@FactorInteger@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9rxynbKTm4ODglphckl/kmVeSmp5a5KCs9j@gKDOvRMFBSyFNQd9BISgxLz012tDAIPY/AA)

Comment: `#^#2&@@@FactorInteger@#&[1]` returns `{1}` in Mathematica. But it works in Mathics.

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks, it wouldn't even have occurred to me to see whether Mathics implements `FactorInteger` differently. :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ḋḅ×ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wR/fDHa2Hpz/cOuH/f2Oz/1EA)

**Explanation**

```
       # output is the list of
  ×ᵐ   # products of each
 ḅ     # block of consecutive equal elements
ḋ      # of the prime factors
       # of the input
```

Comment: Congrats on your first Brachylog answer! ...at least I think?

Comment: @Fatalize: My 2nd I think. I had [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96731/47066) from before. Definitely my shortest one though :)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>3</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

+2 bytes to fix the edge case of `1`. Thanks to Riley for the patch (and for the test suite, my 05ab1e is not that strong!)

```
ÒγP1K
```

Test suite at **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#DZBLUUVREAMN9eJk/qOBDXsKG68KG1hBAnssXY6AJN15fT2/338/73p7eD6E4QRJ0QyLDhIy5ChQokKNBi12sJsxzLHAEiusscEWP7jwW@l44IkX3vjgSxxChBF3MYgkimhiiCUPKdJIJy9QkkU2OeRShxJllFNBXd6imhpq6UOLNtrpoJO@Ok0PvcxhxBjjTDDJFHNth1n2sGKNdTbYZItt9p6xn/8)**

#### How?

```
Ò     - prime factorisation, with duplicates
 γ    - split into chunks of consecutive equal elements
  P   - product of each list
   1  - literal one
    K - removed instances of top from previous
      - implicitly display top of stack
```

Comment: @Adnan is that the best link for "bytes" or is there a formatted code page somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, there is a [code-page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) that displays all bytes.

Comment: Oh, how'd I miss it >_< Thanks ever so much :)

Comment: Does not work for `1`.

Comment: @LeakyNun fixed up with help :)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
&YF^1X-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@68W6RZnGKH7/7@FAQA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#s1JyCFNX0LVTUM9w@K8W6RZnGKH7Pyzjv6UlAA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `80`  as an example.

```
&YF    % Implicit input. Push array of unique prime factors and array of exponents
       % STACK: [2 3 5], [4 0 1]
^      % Power, element-wise
       % STACK: [16 1 5]
1      % Push 1
       % STACK: [16 1 5], 1
X-     % Set difference, keeping order. Implicitly display
       % STACK: [16 5]
```

---

*EDIT (June 9, 2017): `YF` with two outputs has been modified in [release 20.1.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/20.1.0): non-factor primes and their (zero) exponents are skipped. This doesn't affect the above code, which works without requiring any changes (but `1X-` could be removed).*

Comment: I assume the change means `1X-` is redundant in the new release... also, that looks like set difference rather than intersection to me.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Correct on both. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
{mF::#1-}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#q9b8X53rZmWlbKhb@7@uoNbQwED/PwA)

Simply separates the input into its constituent prime powers and removes `1`s (only necessary for input `1`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

`(2#)` is an anonymous function taking an integer and returning a list.

Use as `(2#) 99`.

```hs
m#n|m>n=[]|x<-gcd(m^n)n=[x|x>1]++(m+1)#div n x
(2#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FZDLahtBEEX3@YqD5cUMg8VUVXd1F0T6kcQBYcm2wNMOkh9a6N@VzvJeuM9ld2ybY/s4nHZPH/ef7e3YDuf1svs7DL/bw/b8@v59pq2HO7ibpvH@PzE808ZxfTrs9uP6@/20P9@WVbsu27b59Xi9/Hx4edoPy582dny5XrbyOE3DMsm42h@/aFx@PG8GXY23m6AYiYxTqAQyI4IoYkhCMuJIQSoS6Ix2jaKGJjSjjha0ooHNmGDd0rCEZcyxglUsSDNJSErqiYmUSU4qpEoK8kwWspKN3AtlspMLuZIDn3HBFTc84b2v4wWveFBmilCUYpREyZQ@p1AqJagzVahKNWqiZqpT@9pKDWImhFDCiERkwolC9DPiHw)

Inspired by the power trick some people used in the recent [squarefree number challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120078/abandon-all-squares-ye-who-divide-me).

- `m#n` generates factors of `n`, starting with `m`.
- If `m>n`, we stop, concluding we've already found all factors.
- `x=gcd(m^n)n` is the largest factor of `n` whose prime factors are all in `m`. Note that because smaller `m` are tested first, this will be `1` unless `m` is prime.
- We include `x` in the resulting list if it's not 1, and then recurse with the next `m`, dividing `n` by `x`. Note that `x` and `div n x` cannot have common factors.
- `(2#)` takes a number and starts finding its factors from `2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
ÆF*/€
```

Test suite at **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4zU1L/1HTmv9BR/ccbgcyvIEYiLJAVMMcBV07hUcNcyP//7e0BAA)**

#### How?

```
ÆF*/€ - Main link: n
ÆF    - prime factors as [prime, exponent] pairs
   /€ - reduce €ach with:
  *   - exponentiation
```

Comment: An alternate 6-byte solution in an attempt to find another method that would tie with yours (unfortunately failing): `ÆfŒgZP`. It has the same number of tokens but too many two-byte atoms ;)

Comment: ...and like my deleted 05ab1e entry it returns `1` for an input of `1` which is disallowed (the effect of performing an empty product).

Comment: :( Well, whoops, overlooked that. Darn. :P

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes

```
Ifw.n$@EOK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@@@ZVq6Xp@Lg6u/9//@HdVsbAA)

Unfortunately, this uses [code points as integer I/O again](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values). The test case in the TIO link is input **191808** which decomposes into **64**, **81** and **37**. Note that this solution prints the prime powers in order from largest to smallest prime, so we get the output `%Q@`.

For convenience, here is a 16-byte solution with decimal I/O which uses the same core algorithm:

```
/O/\K
\i>fw.n$@E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6/vrx/jzRWTaZdWrpen4uD6/7@hpaGFgQUA)

#### Explanation

As the other answers, this decomposes the input into prime powers.

```
I      Read a code point as input.
f      Compute its prime factorisation a prime/exponent pairs and push them
       to the stack in order from smallest to largest prime.
w      Remember the current IP position on the return address stack. This
       starts a loop.
  .      Duplicate the current exponent. This will be zero once all primes
         have been processed.
  n$@    Terminate the program if this was zero.
  E      Raise the prime to its corresponding power.
  O      Output the result as a character.
K      Return to the w to run the next loop iteration.
```

Answer (score 2):

### mathematica 46 bytes

```
#[[1]]^#[[2]]&/@If[#==1,#={},FactorInteger@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9rxwdbRgbGwekjGJj1fQdPNOilW1tDXWUbatrddwSk0vyizzzSlLTU4sclGPV/gcUZeaVKDhoKaQp6DsoBCXmpadGGxoYxP4HAA)

Comment: Nice answer, but it's giving slightly incorrect output for some of the test cases. Currently [your code outputs](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P975ZZVFyi7@CWmFySX@SZV5KanlrkoKz2P6AoM69EwUFLIU1B30EhKDEvPTXa0MAg9j8A) `{}; {2}; {3}; {2}; {5}; {2,3}; {7}; {2}; {3}; {2,5}; {11}; {2,3}; {13}; ...` but it should output `{}; {2}; {3}; {4}; {5}; {2,3}; {7}; {8}; {9}; {2,5}; {11}; {4,3}; {13}; ...` instead.

Comment: I think I fixed it

Comment: Seems to work in [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9rxwdbRgbGwekjGJj1fQdPNOilW1tDXWUbatrddwSk0vyizzzSlLTU4sclGPV/gcUZeaVKDhoKaQp6DsoBCXmpadGGxoYxP4HAA) indeed. +1 Oh, and welcome to PPCG, I see you're fairly new here. You've probably already seen it, but if not, [Tips for golfing in Mathematica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica) might be interesting to read through. Enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: If you find yourself accessing the components of `#` more than `#` itself, you can save a lot of bytes by using `Apply` (`@@@`) instead of `Map` (`/@`): `#^#2&@@@If...`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 28 bytes

```
n->[x[1]^x[2]|x<-factor(n)~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1OwVfifp2sXXRFtGBtXEW0UW1Nho5uWmFySX6SRp1kX@z8NxACqMtRRsLTUUSgoyswr0cjTUVBS0LVTUNJRSAMq09T8DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 62 Bytes

prints a associative array with the prime as key and how often the prime is use as value and nothing for input `1`

```
for($i=2;1<$n=&$argn;)$n%$i?++$i:$n/=$i+!++$r[$i];print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVTI0UrL@n5ZfpKGSaWtkbWijkmerBpay1lTJU1XJtNfWVsm0UsnTt1XJ1FYEcoqiVTJjrQuKMvNK4oG6ijSt//8HAA)

Output for `60`

```
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

## PHP, 82 Bytes

```php
for($i=2;1<$n=&$argn;)$n%$i?++$i:$n/=$i+!($r[$i]=$r[$i]?$r[$i]*$i:$i);print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JYy9DkBAEAZ7b0E@4lwhlNbmHkRENNhmXTbe//xVU8xkxhCPmGG1Xbno@oLSdloN4Z66EcrVp8hBS0jwHjJAW4b4vIZNkJl/hB/NG4ijaKLX8pzMUUo3)

prints nothing for input `1` if you wish a empty array instead and a sorted array it will be a little longer

```
for($r=[],$i=2;1<$n=&$argn;)$n%$i?++$i:$n/=$i+!($r[$i]=$r[$i]?$r[$i]*$i:$i);sort($r);print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
w⌠iⁿ⌡M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@1/@qGdB5qPG/Y96Fvr@/29mAAA)

Explanation:

```
w⌠iⁿ⌡M
w       factor into [prime, exponent] pairs
 ⌠iⁿ⌡M  for each pair:
  i       flatten
   ⁿ      prime**exponent
```

Answer (score 0):

## [miniML](https://github.com/feresum/acml/tree/master/miniml), 47 bytes

Challenges involving prime factorization are terribly over-represented here, so we are all sadly forced to have factorization in the standard library.

```
fun n->map(fun p->ipow(fst p)(snd p))(factor n)
```

Note that the 'mini' in miniml refers to the size of the feature set, not the size of source code written in it.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 61 bytes

```ruby
require 'prime'
->n{(2..n).select{|e|n/e.to_f%1==0&&e.prime?}}
```

I'm really disappointed after looking 6-7 byte solutions -))

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Power@@@FactorInteger@#&
```

Too bad `@@@*` is not a thing. Also, I'd like `/@*`, `@@*`, and in fact, change `@@@` to `/@@`, `//@` to `@@@` or whatever and add the infinite family of `//@`, `///@`, ...