# Find the perfect square!

Tags: code-golf, math

Your task is to turn a square root like this:

```
√12
```

into a form like this:

```
2√3
```

For our purpose, we only need to output the left number here:

```
2
```

### Test cases

```
4  -> 2
9  -> 3
12 -> 2
13 -> 1
108-> 6
```

### Specifications

- You may assume for the input that \$n>0\$. \$n\$ has to be as large as possible.
- If the number is already a perfect square, do this:

```
√4 = 2√1 -> 2
```

- If the number doesn't contain perfect squares, do this:

```
√13 = 1√13 -> 1
```

Comment: Related: [Simplify a square root](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83814/20260), which has you return both parts of `a√b`.

Comment: I think that `n=0` is an [exceptional edge case](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17611/20260) that would be better to disallow, since 0 can be expressed as `0√b` or `a√0` for any `a` or `b`. And if we consider simplest form to mean taking `a` as big as possible in `a√b`, there's no limit on how big `a` can be.

Comment: For reference, this is [A000188](https://oeis.org/A000188).

Comment: Hmm...  it isn't clear to me from the challenge whether we need to supply the *largest* ```a``` if there is more-than-one ```a√b``` solution (as implied by xnor), or whether *any* ```a``` is Ok.  If the former, I'll need to add one more byte to my answer.  Suggest test case 108 to clarify (√108 = 2√27, and 3√12, as well as 6√3).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Although it was indeed not clear from the challenge description prior, and `108` is a nice additional test case. If either the lowest or highest (or any) \$a\$ would be allowed, an output of `1` would suffice for every possible input, since \$1\sqrt{b}\$ would be valid - in which case I could have a 0-byte solution in Retina. ;)

Comment: You provide an example and you provide test cases but you don't actually describe what it is that we're supposed to be doing here (I had to derive it from the existing solutions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplify a square root](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83814/simplify-a-square-root)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think you'll find that `^` is a 1-byte solution...

Comment: the result is max quadratic inside factor of a number

Comment: Why was this closed as unclear? All things in the comments have been address. `n=0` has been removed as edge case, and it mentions "_\$n\$ has to be as large as possible._" so we know we're looking for the maximum.

Comment: @Neil Woops, you're indeed correct. Forgot we had to take input, haha. xD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think what happened is that the question got 3 unclear votes before it was clarified, and then two votes as duplicate (but unclear was still the majority close reason)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt)  `-mx`,  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

<sup>[*Crossed out &nbsp4;&nbsp; is no longer 4 :)*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)</sup>

```
²vN
```

My first Japt answer. :)
Port of [my first 5-byter 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206857/52210), but with smart use of Japt's flags for the range and sum.

-1 byte thanks to *@Shaggy* thanks to the [shortcuts list](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=sg#docs-shortcuts): `p)`/`p␠` to `²`

[Try it online.](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=snZO&input=MTA4)

**Explanation:**

```python
-m       # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a ranged list [0, input)
  ²      # Square each value in the list, and implicitly close the function
   vN    # Check which values are divisible by the input (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
     -x  # After which the sum is calculated of the resulting list
         # (before the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: These Japt flags should be counted as part of the code :(

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate No, they don't. Flags used to count towards the byte-count in the past, but they now count as different languages (i.e. Japt is a different language than Japt `-mx`) since [Dec. 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/52210).

Comment: I know that this is the current consensus, but flags like this are the exact reason why command line flags used to be counted.

Comment: Welcome to Japt! :) Looks like you were posting as I was fighting with the SE app; I'll delete mine momentarily. Couple of quick tips: `1.` a space is enough to close a single method in Japt (although the `)` doesn't make a difference here `2.` There's a [shortcut](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6#docs-shortcuts) for `  p2<space>` which will allow you to get this down to 3 bytes.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate, consensus is consensus ;) If you don't like this one then you can have your say by downvoting it at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/

Comment: @Shaggy There is only one answer there, and I'm not willing to write another one. There is also a consensus at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5076 (and I don't think embedding merely *half* of the code in the "implementation" makes it much better)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I agree that putting everything in flags and posting a 0-byte answer isn't very good sports (although technically allowed now). But with Japt and similar languages using flags like Perl, C# Visual Compiler, etc. the amount of flags that can be used is pretty limited, and are for a specific builtins (range and sum in this case), so I personally don't see a difference tbh. Some languages always sum implicitly at the end by default; Japt does it with a flag; 05AB1E does it with a single byte `O`; and with a verbose language you'll have to use `.sum()` or a manual loop.

Comment: @Shaggy Out of curiosity: is [`o²mvN x`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=b7Jtdk4geA&input=MTA4) what should be used without those two flags? Or is there a shorter way without changing the actual method?

Comment: You can run each element through a function as you're summing so `õ²xvU` would do it for 5 bytes, Kevin.

Comment: @Shaggy Ah, of course.. Just put the `x` at the position of the `m` to sum the mapped `"v",N` values, thanks. And both `o` (\$[0,n)\$) and `õ` (\$[1,n]\$) indeed work in this case, although technically `-m` is equal to `o`. :) I'll see if I can do a few more easy challenges in Japt before trying something a bit more complex perhaps.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, I'll keep an eye out for them, so.

Comment: @Shaggy You need to fix your header generation to put a space after the `#` as CommonMark now requires.

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LnIÖO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ8/z8DT///8NjQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/n7zKw9P8/@v8jzbQMdQx0bHUMTTSMTTWMTaLBQA).

**Previous <s>9</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:**

```
LR.ΔnÖ
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ0jv3JS8w9P@/zc0AgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf99gvTOTTm0rjjv8LT/tTr/ow10DHVMdCx1DI10DI11jM1iAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
L       # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 n      # Take the square of each value in the list
  IÖ    # Check which squares are divisible by the input (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
    O   # And sum those checks
        # (after which this sum is output implicitly as result)

L       # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 R      # Reverse it to [input, 1]
  .Δ    # Find the first value in this list which is truthy for:
    n   #  Square the current value
     Ö  #  Check if the (implicit) input is evenly divisible by this square
        # (after which the found value is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Sadly there's no inverse to `Ó`; the best I could do was `Ó2÷ā<ØsmP`, which is as long as your first answer, but hopefully more efficient at least.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, when I saw the Jelly answer of Jonathan I was indeed looking for a port as well and had that exact same `Ó2÷ā<ØsmP`. I like this challenge, because there are quite a few slightly different approaches to get the same answers. :) And it's indeed unfortunate there isn't an inverse of `Ó` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ḷ²%ċ0
```

Uses the formula from [the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000188): the number of solutions to $$x^2 \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ n)$$
Explanation:

- implicit input
- range `0..n-1`,
- square each
- modulo input (I got this part to work via trial and error)
- count zeroes
- implicit print

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2HNqke6Tb4//@/pamFuaGlMQA)

Comment: An upvote of my 6 byter bought me here, didn't know of this method. You can do it in four bytes with `ḍ²€S` [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjt5Dmx41rQn@//@/oYEFAA). That is, square each of the implicit `[1..n]` with `²€`, check if `n` divides each with `ḍ` (same result for `n²` as you'd get for `0²`), then sum with `S`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan nice; I'll never understand Jelly

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog),  <sup>8 6</sup> 5 bytes

*-1 thanks to Unrelated String*

```
f↔∋√ℕ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtPiAidz/ihrDigoLhuol94bWQ/2bihpTiiIviiJrihJX//1s0LDksMTIsMTMsMzAwXQ)

#### How it works

```
f↔∋√ℕ
    ℕ output is a natural number (≥0) that is
   √  the root of … (Brachylog gives the negative root first)
  ∋   an element …
f↔    in the reverse factors list (so search starts with bigger values)
```

### Alternative version with prime factors, 10 bytes

```
{ḋp⊇~j×}ᵘ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/rhju6CR13tdVmHp9c@3Dojv@T/f0Pj/1EA) or verify [all test cases](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7r64Y7ugkdd7XVZh6fXPtw6I78ESE74/z/aRMdSx9BIx9BYx9jAIPZ/FAA).

#### How it works

```
{ḋp⊇~j×}ᵘ⌉
         ⌉  take the maximum of …
{      }ᵘ   all unique …
      ×       multiplications of …   10
    ~j        halves of …            [2,5]
   ⊇          ordered subsets from … [2,5,2,5]
  p           the permutations of …  [2,5,2,5,3]
 ḋ            the prime factors      [2,2,3,5,5]
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtPiAidz/ihrDigoLhuol94bWQ/2bihpTiiIviiJrihJX//1s0LDksMTIsMTMsMzAwXQ). Funnily enough, that only occurred to me after I'd tried substituting in `~^₂` for the *same* byte count...

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=n)=>n/k%k?f(n,k-1):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjTyfbNk/T1i5PP1s12z4NxNc11LTK/p@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYaKgoKmpoK@vYMSFKmEJkzBGkzA0wqHD0BgqYYguYWABkTD7DwA)

#### How?

We recursively look for the greatest \$k\le n\$ such that \$\dfrac{n}{k}\equiv 0\pmod k\$, which is guaranteed to be satisfied for \$k=1\$ in the worst case.

This is a more golf-friendly way of testing \$\dfrac{n}{k^2}\equiv 0\pmod 1\$.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆE:2ÆẸ
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer which yields a positive integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm6uV0eG2h7t2/P//39DU2NLE2NwSAA)** Or see the [first 100](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm6uV0eG2h7t2/Dc0MDjc/qhpzf//hqbGlibG5pYA).

#### How?

```
ÆE:2ÆẸ - Link: integer, X          e.g. 9587193
ÆE     - factorisation vector (X)       [0,1,0,4,3] (since 2°×3¹×5°×7⁴×11³=9587193)
  :2   - integer divide by two          [0,0,0,2,1]
    ÆẸ - evaluate factorisation vector  539         (since 2°×3°×5°×7²×11¹=539)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 5 bytes

<sup>(this was produced by trying a bunch of languages from https://github.com/ETHproductions/golfing-langs until I found one that had the most useful built-ins for this problem)</sup>

```
dụ⁇)u
```

Explanation:

```
d     divisors
 ụ⁇   keep only squares
   )  take last
    u square root
```

[Try it online! (example stolen from the Jelly answer)](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P@Xh7qWPGts1S///tzS1MDe0NP4PAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
n=i=input()
while n%i**2:i-=1
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpbCoAgEAXQ/7sKEYIKgsbegqsJwYGYJIxq9Ub0fU58UtjF5Cvw5hVZf/tVa53FsWOJZyor/CYF17Wx3DhCPFiS4vxNgkGHHgNGTJixgFoQgcwL)

**38 bytes**

```python
lambda n:sum(x*x%n<1for x in range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBDoIwEAXQ/T/FbExaV04FFZCbuCmBShMYmlJiPX31bV/4pnkTU1z/Kotdh9GStPuxqnzOJ3my2yJl8kLRyntSonX5zH6ZiFvpvYQjKd2F6CWR@29hGFxRocYNdzzQgC9gBpsf)

Based on the solution of [my pronoun is monicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206877/20260), counting the number of solutions to  \$x^2 \equiv 0 \ (\mathbb{mod}\ n)\$ for \$x\$ from \$0\$ to \$n-1\$.

Answer (score 5):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) machine code,  <s>20</s>  17 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> ≈ 22 bytes

*As per the exception described [in this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10810/58563), the exact score is **21.25 bytes** (170 bits)*

A routine expecting the input number in **R0** and returning the result in **R3**.

```
1D2     |         CLRR    R2
1C9     |         CLRR    R1
0D1     | @@loop  ADDR    R2,     R1
00A     |         INCR    R2
084     |         MOVR    R0,     R4
10C     | @@sub   SUBR    R1,     R4
10C     |         SUBR    R1,     R4
114     |         SUBR    R2,     R4
22E 004 |         BGT     @@sub
20C 001 |         BNEQ    @@next
093     |         MOVR    R2,     R3
141     | @@next  CMPR    R0,     R1
226 00D |         BLE     @@loop
0AF     |         JR      R5
```

#### How?

The CP-1610 has no multiplication, no division, no modulo. We want to implement an algorithm that relies on additions and subtractions exclusively.

We start with \$k=0\$. At each iteration, we update \$j\$ in such a way that:

$$j = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$

The good thing about this formula is that it's very easy to compute iteratively: we just need to add \$k\$ to \$j\$ and increment \$k\$ afterwards.

In order to test whether \$n\$ is divisible by \$k^2\$, we initialize a variable \$x\$ to \$n\$ and subtract \$k^2\$ until \$x\le 0\$.

We do not explicitly store \$k^2\$, but it can be easily obtained with:

$$2j+k=k(k-1)+k=k^2$$

Each time we end up with \$x=0\$, we update the final answer to \$k\$.

We stop when \$j\$ is greater than \$n\$.

[Here is a link](https://tio.run/##fZLNboMwEITvPMVUysEIpSE9lpJnCSUmgIkd2Uuhinj2dG1SlTRqffLPt@PZ0bbFR@FK25xprc1BXq8VcmjkO1wiQPEhzXjThg3u1mbD142DEgprbGNs8BIxezCh1hclOVR2X9KfDwVJtIFQSfIo2ujSypPUBBWg0TvKfkGOCksYGqrn9yig/usHvc6Y82s0H0esc7TZ8hlw/TvZoiQ2XFlzwvgfTENTyiWg/lJTS7UJQ910UozYIY2zGQ5XrMIhHq3kWCyoLjTSuZumEk9jvOzIp1NhkGC6rCFH/qf7RPrdnpUOS0fB0C1xqn2Z6zsCmVu0U/TjrMUb5xis@bqjgdE3h/OTN2Ul9VZ7nSyarpWxgmcF24xHhpFtyjOikyQOA1Aa7UwnnztzFPtCrC56ihleXSqh42kfe4Uv) to an implementation of the algorithm in low-level JS.

#### Full commented test code

```
        ROMW    10                ; use 10-bit ROM width
        ORG     $4800             ; map this program at $4800

PNUM    QEQU    $18C5             ; EXEC routine: print a number
MULT    QEQU    $1DDC             ; EXEC routine: signed multiplication

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  main code                                                    ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
main    PROC

        SDBD                      ; set up an interrupt service routine
        MVII    #isr,   R0        ; to do some minimal STIC initialization
        MVO     R0,     $100
        SWAP    R0
        MVO     R0,     $101

        EIS                       ; enable interrupts

        MVII    #$200,  R3        ; R3 = backtab pointer
        SDBD                      ; R4 = pointer to test cases
        MVII    #@@tc,  R4

@@loop  MVI@    R4,     R0        ; R0 = next test case
        TSTR    R0                ; stop if it's 0
        BEQ     @@done

        PSHR    R4                ; save R4
        PSHR    R3                ; save R3
        CALL    pSquare           ; invoke our routine
        MOVR    R3,     R0        ; copy the result into R0
        PULR    R3                ; restore R3
        CALL    print             ; print the result
        PULR    R4                ; restore R4
        B       @@loop            ; go on with the next test case

@@done  DECR    R7                ; done: loop forever

        ;; test cases
@@tc    DECLE   4, 9, 12, 13, 108, 300, 800, 900
        DECLE   0

        ENDP

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  prints the result of a test case                             ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
print   PROC

        PSHR    R5                ; save the return address on the stack

        MVII    #4,     R1        ; R1 = number of digits
        MOVR    R3,     R4        ; R4 = backtab pointer
        ADDI    #5,     R3        ; advance by 5 characters for the next one
        PSHR    R3                ; save R3
        CLRR    R3                ; R3 = attributes (black)
        CALL    PNUM              ; invoke the EXEC routine
        PULR    R3                ; restore R3

        PULR    R7                ; return

        ENDP

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  ISR                                                          ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
isr     PROC

        MVO     R0,     $0020     ; enable display
        MVI     $0021,  R0        ; color-stack mode

        CLRR    R0
        MVO     R0,     $0030     ; no horizontal delay
        MVO     R0,     $0031     ; no vertical delay
        MVO     R0,     $0032     ; no border extension
        MVII    #$D,    R0
        MVO     R0,     $0028     ; light-blue background
        MVO     R0,     $002C     ; light-blue border
        MVO     R0,     $002C     ; light-blue border

        JR      R5                ; return from ISR

        ENDP

        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
        ;;  our routine                                                  ;;
        ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
pSquare PROC

        CLRR    R2                ; R2 = k
        CLRR    R1                ; R1 = k(k - 1) / 2

@@loop  ADDR    R2,     R1        ; add R2 to R1
        INCR    R2                ; k++

        MOVR    R0,     R4        ; start with R4 = n

@@sub   SUBR    R1,     R4        ; subtract 2 * (k(k - 1) / 2) = k² - k
        SUBR    R1,     R4        ; from R4
        SUBR    R2,     R4        ; subtract k from R4
        BGT     @@sub             ; until R4 is less than or equal to 0

        BNEQ    @@next            ; did we reach exactly 0? ...

        MOVR    R2,     R3        ; ... yes: update R3

@@next  CMPR    R0,     R1        ; go on while R1 is less than or
        BLE     @@loop            ; equal to R0

        JR      R5                ; return

        ENDP
```

#### Output

This is the output for the following test cases:

```
4, 9, 12, 13, 108, 300, 800, 900
```

[image: output]

*<sup>screenshot from [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/%7Eim14u2c/intv/)</sup>*

---

*<sub>1. A CP-1610 opcode is encoded with a 10-bit value (0x000 to 0x3FF), known as a 'DECLE'.</sub>*

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[0^mod(x^2)n|x<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7a4NDfaIC43P0WjIs5IM6@mwkY32lBPLy829n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmgJI0tAo9v@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA)

Based on the solution of [my pronoun is monicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206877/20260), counting the number of solutions to  \$x^2 \equiv 0 \ (\mathbb{mod}\ n)\$ using the range from 1 to n.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f n=until((<1).mod n.(^2))pred n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoAgDADAr3RwgEESmOUlRpMGQYlQG8HvW73pDmxnLEUkAfmHei5KTVabem1ARq1Oa77jf6mYCTzwnanDABUZEszWGOsWeUMquDcZA/MH)

Start with `n` and repeatedly take the `pred`ecessor, `until` it satiafies this condition: when we square it and take the original `n` modulo it, the result is less than 1, that is equal to 0.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

```
.+
$*
((^1|11\2)+)\1*$
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLS0MjzrDG0DDGSFNbM8ZQS4VLRdno/38TLksuQyMuQ2MuQwMLAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
((^1|11\2)+)
```

Find the largest square number...

```
\1*$
```

... that divides the input...

```
$#2
```

... and output its root.

Bonus 63-byte version that for an input of `√1`, `√2`, `√3`, `√4`, `√5`, `√6`, `√7`, `√8`, `√9`... outputs `1`, `√2`, `√3`, `2`, `√5`, `√6`, `√7`, `2√2`, `3`... etc. (Previous bonus version did not handle `√1` correctly.)

```
\d+
$*
r`(?=^.(\3)+)(.)\3*((1$|11\4)+)
$#4$2$#1
\D1$

^1(\D)
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi6soQcPeNk5PI8ZYU1tTQ08zxlhLQ8NQpcbQMMYEKMKlomyiYqSibMgV42KowsUVZ6gR4wIUNfz//1HHLEMuIGECIixBhKERmDQGkwYWAA)

Comment: Damn you beat me to Retina, and with a much more elegant solution :o

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
√#/._^_:>1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1HHLGV9vfi4eCs7Q7X/AUWZeSXRyrp2aQ7KsWp1wcmJeXXVXCY6CpY6CoZGQGwMxAYWQL6phbmhpTFX7X8A)

For an integer argument, `√` (`Sqrt`) returns in the desired `a√b` form (unless the argument was a perfect square).

Then, `/._^_:>1` matches `Power` expressions and replaces them with 1. As `a√b` expands to `Times[a,Power[b,1/2]]`, it becomes `Times[a,1]=a`.

Comment: wow, excellent +1

Comment: A Mathematica answer with no letters? What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>44</s> <s>33</s></sup> 32 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=n;n%(--i*i););n=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBha4MwEIa/@ysOi5C0cau6jpXUfhn7FVNGMXE92M5i3JCJv92d1o52gYTL3fO@uVwRvhfFMKAuBcmurGqBKWkKRBjiEqWWmlLU/bBAKj6@jIWdawxWd8e9h9TA5wFJfFdopNd5wKs4Huol1K85pND5WfsSZ@32mffGV3B9T/xeT4rRprGueaOz6EFtVRSrKFHR@umKse3Jto01EwVdrBLFlHqcEW4dxMghGdsystZzuAOHP7YqxcVB3s8JxqWG1WriJJx/cHmP2GPua6rn@qbsuDzO7DZrOfvX6H/ZqWakFH5gINwDn4HLiMdCCpzimbElq/PZsvf64Rc)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44</s> (crossed-out) <s>36</s>  <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```r
((n=scan()):1)[!n%%(n:1)^2][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0Mjz7Y4OTFPQ1PTylAzWjFPVVUjD8iKM4qNNoz9b2hgwfUfAA)

Or, a completely-different [25 byte](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V0NRw9BKI8@2ODkxT0NTUzPOSFU1T/O/oYEF138A) approach based on equivalence to 'number of solutions to x^2==0(mod n)' (as pointed-out by [my pronoun is monicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206853/find-the-perfect-square/206877#206877)), but that wasn't my own idea and hence seems to me to be cheating:
`sum(!(1:(n=scan()))^2%%n)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 15 bytes

```
n->core(n,1)[2]
```

Yes, there is a build-in.

> `core(n,{flag=0})`: unique squarefree integer `d` dividing `n` such that `n/d` is a square. If (optional) flag is non-null, output the two-component row vector
> `[d,f]`, where `d` is the unique squarefree integer dividing `n` such that `n/d=f^2` is a square.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y45vyhVI0/HUDPaKPZ/YkFBTqVGnoKunUJBUWZeCZCpBOIoKaRp5Glq6ihEm@goWOooGBoBsXGs5n8A)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```java
n->{for(var c=n++;c/--n%n>0;);return n;}
```

Inspired by [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206856/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BbsIwDIbvPMUvJKRETbt1IKQRwRvAhSPjkKUBhRUXpW6nqeqzdyn0YtmW/8/fzbQmvRU/gy1NXWNvPHUzwBO7cDHW4TCOQFE136WDFVNDUsd9P4ulZsPe4gDCdqB0112qIFoTYLeUJNq@pSktaPeupQ6Om0Ag3Q96jD4iK0YnQlv5AvdoII4cPF1PZxj5ej8ioxM8NiD3O/qdzl2uVupT5R8qX6rlupfPU@D4V7O7Z1XD2SNyuCThk/nmi@cJZVZ4Obn3wz8)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                // Method with double as both parameter and return-type
  for(var c=n       //  Create a copy `c` of the input `n`
             ++     //  Then increase `n` by 1
      ;             //  Continue looping as long as:
       c/--n        //   (decrease `n` by 1 first before every iteration with `--n`)
                    //   `c` divided by `n`
            %n>0;)  //   is NOT a multiply of `n` nor 0
  ;return n;}       //  After the loop: return the modified `n` as result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 15 bytes

```
q~_{_*1$%!},,\;
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r~_%7B_*1%24%25!%7D%2C%2C%5C%3B&input=135)

Uses the new method in [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206857/58707).

---

**[CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 21 bytes**
*This is my old approach to the problem, pre-[Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s new method which I don't understand*

```
q~mF{[~2/]}%{~#}%{*}*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~mF%7B%5B~2%2F%5D%7D%25%7B~%23%7D%25%7B*%7D*&input=675)

---

*Explanation*

```
q~                     Translate input into a CJam object (allows for easier testing)
  mF                   Factorise with exponents
    {     }%           For each factor
      ~2/              Halve the exponent [and round down]
     [   ]             Capture the base & exponent in an array
            {  }%      For each transformed factor
             ~#        Expand the base and exponent into b^e
                 {*}*  Multiply all the transformed factors together
```

This approach removes all single factors (those that would make up the radical part) whilst halving the paired factors (equivalent to square rooting the integer part).

---

**[CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 23 bytes**
*A CJam port of [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206857/58707)*

```
q~_,(;{_*1$\%0>!},\;)\;
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_%2C(%3B%7B_*1%24%5C%250%3E!%7D%2C%5C%3B)%5C%3B&input=675)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

Now based on @someone's formula.

```
ＮθＩＬΦθ¬﹪×ιιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMMnNS@9JEPDLTOnBCSpo@CXX6Lhm59SmpOvEZKZm1qskamjkKmpo1CoCQbW//8bGv3XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. For each number from `0` to the input, calculates whether its square is divisible by the input, and takes the number of matches.

Alternative version, also 12 bytes:

```
ＮθＩΣＥθ¬﹪×ιιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcG7CoAgFADQva9wvIINtTo2NShB/YCZkOC7a79/o3PsbZrNJhCtqXTUPZ6uQeVy2JpPCIt5EPYeQZkCVTCdEVS@eshw@Oge8IJ5LljlP0k0zTS@4QM) Link is to verbose version of code. For each number from `0` to the input, calculates whether its square is divisible by the input, and takes the sum of the results.

Alternative version, also 12 bytes:

```
ＮθＩ№Ｅθ﹪×ιιθ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObEYSOSXApm@iQUahToKvvkppTn5GiGZuanFGpk6CpmaOgqFmkDCQFNT0/r/f0Oj/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. For each number from `0` to the input, calculates the remainder when its square is divisible by the input, and counts the number of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
ef!%Q^T2S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzVNUTUwLsQo@P9/S0sA)

```
ef!%Q^T2S   
        S   Create range from 1 to (implicit) input
 f          Filter keep from the above, as T, where:
     ^T2      Square T
   %Q         Mod the input with the above
  !           Logical NOT
e           Take the last (largest) element of the filtered list, implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)!

```
▲fo¬%1m√Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TWn5h9aoGuY@6pj1cEfX////LQE) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9odXNr/23igoH/4payZm/CrCUxbeKImuG4iv///1s0LDksMTIsMTNd)

#### Commented

```haskell
▲          -- the maximum of ...
 fo        -- ... filter on the next two functions composed
   ¬       --     - boolean negate / (== 0)
    %1     --     - modulo 1
      m√   -- ... map square root on ...
        Ḋ  -- ... the list of divisors
```

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TWn5h9aoGuY@6pj1cEfX////LQE "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## perl -MList::Util=max -pl, 34 bytes

```
$n=$_;$_=max grep!($n%$_**2),1..$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lz1Yl3lol3jY3sUIhvSi1QFFDJU9VJV5Ly0hTx1BPTyXv/38TLksuQyMuQ2MuE4t/@QUlmfl5xf91fX0yi0usrEJLMnNAmv/rFuQAAA)

This finds the largest square which properly divides the input number. Very inefficient as it tries all numbers from 1 up to the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->n,x=n{x-=1while n%x**2>0;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5Pp8I2r7pC19awPCMzJ1UhT7VCS8vIzsC6ovZ/tImOpY6hkY6hsY6hgYWOYaxeamJyRnVNXo1CgUa1Qp6CrZ1CWnRerEKtpkLtfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
1#.0=[|2^~i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1DGyja4zi6jL1/mv@T1Mw4UpTsFQAEoZGIMIYzDSwAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [<s>12</s> 10 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
·£æ9Š3nòy├
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=K3Z7ISh2XjIlfVx+&input=NAo5CjEyCjEzCjEwOA==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `+v{!(v^2%}\~`

Uses the formula from the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000188) page: the number of solutions to \$x^2≡0 (\mod n)\$

```
              ~     1-range (inclusive) to
                _   variable initialized to STDIN; implied
            +\      folded with addition after
v{                  mapping with block (key of v)
  !                 Boolean NOT
    (               Begin expression
          v         
        ^           exponentiated by
          2         two 
      %             mod
        _           implied
    )               End expression; implied
}                   End block
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 71 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _STDIN_as_integer][T    T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _n=Duplicate_input][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S T S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_input][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_n][S N
S _Duplicate_n][T   S S N
_Multiply][T    S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_RESULT][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_RESULT][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDMBnEVgCJQEkxzcSpwAtWA5ECCUBkuEI8LpPL/f0MjAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Port of [*@Sok*'s Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206862/52210), so make sure to upvote him! Whitespace doesn't have decimals, so his/her approach is ideal for Whitespace since it doesn't use square-root nor regular division, but only integers.

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = STDIN as integer
Integer r = n
Start LOOP:
  Integer s = r * r
  If(n % s == 0):
    Jump to Label PRINT
  r = r - 1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

Label PRINT:
  Print r as integer to STDOUT
  (implicitly stop the program with an error: no exit defined)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 52 bytes

```
define f(n){for(i=n;i--;){if(!(n%(i*i))){return i}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcQxCoAwDAXQvaeog/AjdFA7KMXLqA1kiVB0Kj17RN/w9sPszCyaPUOp8lUgmyYJIVEVRgftIYMQUS35fop6aa2ZMSI5xvo1Tv/zd1zIvQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki), <s>123</s> 72 bytes

```
.+                        We convert the input into unary
$&*_ $&*_                 and create a copy for factor checking
{` (_+)                   START LOOP: We square the input by multiplying
$& $.1*$1                 its string representation by its length
(?=^.* (_+) (_+))\2+ .+   We check if the square is a factor of the input
$.1                       if so we replace the whole text with the current counter
 (_*)_.*                  Otherwise we decrement the counter by one
 $1                       ---
-- IMPLICIT LOOP END --
-- IMPLICIT OUTPUT --
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0VNK14BRHBVJyhoxGtrAkUUVPQMtVQMuTTsbeP0tMCiYEIzxkhbAaRHz5ALKKClGa@nxaWgYqjw/7@hEQA)

---

This approach is essentially a port of [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206857/58707).
It checks all the numbers from the input downwards until it finds a number whose square divides the original.

---

*-51 bytes*: Many thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil), whose suggestion helped me to cut off a ridiculous amount of code.

I've also switched from separating with newlines to separating with spaces because `.` is anti-newline.

Comment: You should consider adding a [TIO](https://tio.run) link. There are probably opportunities for golfing this down, both in minor tweaks such as using `{` for `+(` but also maybe more complex simplifications such as using Retina 1's `*` operator do perform squaring.

Comment: Line 2: `*` defaults to `$&*_`. This means that you don't need the `$&` at the start or the `_` at the end.

Comment: Line 3: You can use ``{`_+$`` instead (use `$&` instead of `$1` on line 4)

Comment: Line 5: This looks like it could be easily simplified if you arrange the numbers in reverse order i.e. use `i*i i n` instead of `n i i*i`.

Comment: Lines 7-8: I think `_ _+$` and a blank line 8 works. (Note that is is pre-reversal so it would be `^_+ _` if you reversed the order as suggested by my previous comment.)

Comment: Thank you for the golfs, I had no clue that `*` defaulted to `$&*_` and the changes to 5&7-8 are really clever, I'll apply them soon

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒²k÷Σ
```

Port of [my 5-byter 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206857/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EmHNmUf3n5u8f//hlxGXCZcllyGRlyGxlzGZlyGBhYA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
       # (could alternatively be `r` for a range [0, input) )
 ²     # Square each value in this list
  k÷   # Check which values are evenly divisible by the input (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
    Σ  # And sum those checks
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 23 chars, 46 bytes

```
{√⍵÷×/(∪a)/⍨2∣≢¨⊂⍨a←π⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{√⍵÷×/(∪a)/⍨2∣≢¨⊂⍨a←π⍵}
  f 4
2
  f 9
3
  f 12
2
  f 13
1
  f 108
6
  f 2×2×2×2×2×3×3
12
```

comment:

```
{√⍵÷×/(∪a)/⍨2∣≢¨⊂⍨a←π⍵}
                    π⍵  factor argument
                  a←    save that in a list "a" of prime factors
                ⊂⍨      partition "a" in a list of list each element is ugual factors found
            2∣≢¨        to each element of list of list find if number of elements is odd
    ×/(∪a)/⍨           so choice in ∪a the elements appear in list of list as odd and multiple them
  ⍵÷                   divide the argument for the number of factor contained odd times
 √                     make sqrt of that
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 16 bytes

```
sum(not(fPart(seq(I²/Ans,I,1,Ans-1
```

Port of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206853/find-the-perfect-square/206877#206877). Takes input in `Ans`. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
R²$Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVIlQzIlQjIlMjQlRTElQjglOEEmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMiZmbGFncz1T)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
R²$Ḋ  # Implicit input
R     # Push [1..input]
 ²    # Square each value
  $   # Push the input again
   Ḋ  # Check for divisibility
      # Sum the resulting list
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
Ď√‼Ṁ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FquP9D3qmPWoYc_DnQ1LipOSi6HiC9aacFlyGRpxGRpzGRpYQAQB)

```
Ď√‼Ṁ
Ď       Divisors
 √      Integer square root; fails if not a perfect square
  ‼     Remove failed values
   Ṁ    Maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```rkt
(define(p x[n x])(if(= 0(modulo x(sqr n)))n(p x(- n 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@7bsJAEEV7f8WVaGYKIz8IAVmIn6CLKFb2OF55GcN6LZyvN0vSpHB5ztx5eVP3EpaNM/oN/wfUSGtV6I75SzFfmWxLJ2R0G5rJDZhpfHgoM@s7QykUeSReIpIX0zAnSVXhImMYEToT8LTOYVD3g7u3GrkTRWusk2aLqkqS2PeYrBfQO5Va/b1mUhtQd1L3aSwbd46T6T8jrtwxihV9ZJQrOi/W43nJ8YsVnx0Ye16KvNx97D8Px@wF)

---

### Explanation

After receiving input, we create a recursive loop that iterates `n` from the input `x` to 1. At each iteration we check whether the input `x` is divisible by the square of `n`. If it is, we return `n`. Note that this loop will never reach 0 as all divisible by `n` when is \$n = 1\$.

$$
  p(x, n=x) =
  \begin{cases}
    n & x \mod n^2 = 0 \\
    p(x, n-1) & otherwise
  \end{cases}
$$

```rkt
(define (perfect-square x [n x])
  (if (zero? (modulo x (sqr n)))
      n
      (perfect-square x (- n 1))))
```

##### What I learnt today

Cool thing I learnt about `define` is the way we can set default arguments to equal previous arguments. If we write `(p 5)`, both `x` and `n` will be set to 5. Saves a ton of bytes. The first draft for this idea was to use a let statement:

```rkt
(define (p x)
  (let loop ([n x])
    ...))
```

### Documentation

- \$x^2 \equiv 0 \mod n\$ ([A000188](https://oeis.org/A000188))
- [Racket's `define`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define%29%29)
- [Racket's `modulo`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._modulo%29%29)

*Have wonderful week ahead!*