# Smallest positive number whose y-th power is divisible by x

Tags: code-golf, integer

## Task

Given integers `x` and `y` which are both at least `2`, find the smallest positive number whose `y`-th power is divisible by `x`.

## Example

Given `x=96` and `y=2`, the output should be `24` since `24` is the smallest positive `n` satisfying `n^2 is divisible by 96`.

## Testcases

```
x  y output
26 2 26
96 2 24
32 3 4
64 9 2
27 3 3
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Solution with lowest byte-count wins.

## References

- `y=2`: [OEIS A019554](http://oeis.org/A019554)
- `y=3`: [OEIS A019555](http://oeis.org/A019555)
- `y=4`: [OEIS A053166](http://oeis.org/A053166)
- `y=5`: [OEIS A015052](http://oeis.org/A015052)
- `y=6`: [OEIS A015054](http://oeis.org/A015053)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18535/48934).

Comment: Will `X` always be greater than `Y`?

Comment: @Fatalize What has that got to do with anything?

Comment: There is no test case where `X` is less than `Y`, and it can reduce the length of some answers (at least mine) if `X` is always greater than `Y`. I would rather have that `X` can be either bigger or smaller, but then one test case for the latter would be great.

Comment: Your references list is the best illustration I've seen of the ridiculous arbitrariness of OEIS entry ordering.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @LeakyNun.*

```
:[I:1]*$r=#>
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OltJOjFdKiRyPSM-&input=Wzk2OjJd&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
               Input = [X, Y]
:[I:1]*        Get a list [X*I, Y] (I being any integer at this point)
       $r=     Get the first integer which is the Yth root of X*I
          #>   This integer must be strictly positive
               This integer is the Output
```

Comment: [1 byte off](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=W1g6WV0sMDwuPTpZXjpYJTAs&input=Wzk2OjJd&args=Wg)

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks. This will be much slower though.

Comment: Why will this be slower?

Comment: [Slower still, but another byte off](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=W1g6WV0sLjpZXjpYJTA8Lj0&input=Wzk2OjJd&args=Wg)

Comment: @LeakyNun Because it will try all integers from 1 up to the answer. whereas my answer would propagate the constraints before assigning a value.

Comment: To quote the famous Fatalize: ["don't care about complexity"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31654498#31654498)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆE÷ĊÆẸ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZFw7fEisOG4bq4&input=&args=OTY+Mg) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZFw7fEisOG4bq4CsOnL-KCrOKBuDsiRw&input=&args=WzI2LCAyXSwgWzk2LCAyXSwgWzMyLCAzXSwgWzY0LCA5XSwgWzI3LCAzXQ).

#### How it works

```
ÆE÷ĊÆẸ  Main link. Arguments: x, y

ÆE      Yield the exponents of x's prime factorization.
  ÷     Divide them by y.
   Ċ    Ceil; round the quotients up to the nearest integer.
    ÆẸ  Return the integer with that exponents in its prime factorization.
```

Comment: [`R*%⁸i0`](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Uiol4oG4aTAKw6cv4oKs4oG4OyJH&input=&args=WzI2LCAyXSwgWzk2LCAyXSwgWzMyLCAzXSwgWzY0LCA5XSwgWzI3LCAzXQ) is also 6 bytes.

Comment: I think that warrants a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES7), 32 bytes

```
f=(x,y,i=1)=>i**y%x?f(x,y,i+1):i
```

Comment: You never defined `f`.  I think you need to assign the function to `f`.

Comment: @kamoroso94 Sorry, I'm forever doing that.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>60</s> <s>43</s> 39 bytes

*Thanks to @LeakyNun and @Sp3000 for help*

```
f=lambda x,y,i=1:i**y%x<1or-~f(x,y,i+1)
```

A function that takes input via argument and returns the output.

**How it works**

The function uses recursion to repeatedly check integers `i`, starting with `i=1`, until one satisfying the required condition, here `i**y%x<1`, is found. This is achieved by taking the logical `or` of the condition and the result of the expression for `i+1` incremented, which here is `-~f(x,y,i+1)`. This expression continuously evaluates as `False` until a satisfying value `j` is found, at which point it evaluates to `True` and recursion stops. Since these are respectively equivalent to `0` and `1` in Python, and the function has repeatedly been adding `1` via the incrementing part, the function returns `(j-1)*False + True + (j-1)*1 = (j-1)*0 + 1 + (j-1)*1 = 1 + j-1 = j`, as required.

[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/CqdRnk)

Comment: `def f(x,y,i=1):¶ while i**y%x:i+=1¶ print(i)`

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks. I just thought of a slightly shorter way to do it (43 vs 44) with recursion.

Comment: 39: `f=lambda x,y,z=1:z**y%x<1or-~f(x,y,z+1)`

Comment: @Sp3000 Doesn't your function return `True` instead of `z`?

Comment: @LeakyNun You're missing the `-~` part, but yes it would return `True` if `x` was 1.

Comment: Since this function only works if it's assigned to the variable `f`, shouldn't that assignment be included in the byte count? Or are those bytes freebies?

Comment: @Jordan The 39 count includes the `f=`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
R*%⁸i0
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Uiol4oG4aTA&input=&args=OTY+Mg) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Uiol4oG4aTAKw6cv4oKs4oG4OyJH&input=&args=WzI2LCAyXSwgWzk2LCAyXSwgWzMyLCAzXSwgWzY0LCA5XSwgWzI3LCAzXQ).

#### How it works

```
R*%⁸i0  Main link. Arguments: x, y

R       Yield range from 1 to x inclusive.
 *      Raise each to power y.
  %⁸    Take modulo of each with base x.
    i0  Find the 1-based index of the first
        occurence of zero, returns.
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 31 bytes

```
x#y=[n|n<-[1..],mod(n^y)x<1]!!0
```

Usage example: `96#2` -> `24`.

Direct implementation: try all integers `n`, keep those that meet the condition and pick the first one.

Comment: Also 31: `x#y=until(\n->mod(n^y)x<1)(+1)0`

Answer (score 4):

## 05AB1E (10 bytes)

```
>GN²m¹ÖiNq
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=PkdOwrJtwrnDlmlOcQ&input=OTYKMg)

- `>` Reads the first argument, increments it, and pushes it on the stack
- `G` pops the stack (`a`) and starts a loop that contains the rest of the program where `N` takes on the value `1, 2, ... a - 1`.
- `N²m` pushes `N` and the second entry from the input history, then pops them both and pushes the first to the power of the second.
- `¹` pushes the first entry from the input history onto the stack.
- `Ö` pops the previous two stack entries, then pushes `a % b == 0` on the stack.
- `i` pops that from the stack. If true, it executes the rest of the program; otherwise, the loop continues.
- `N` pushes `N` on the stack.
- `q` terminates the program.

When the program terminates, the top value of the stack is printed.

Comment: Please post an explanation of how this code works for those nto familiar with your language, but otherwise good job, and nice first post.

Comment: That link seems interesting.

Comment: Very nice first answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
y:w^w\&X<
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eTp3XndcJlg8&input=OTYKMg)

#### Explanation

```
y       % Take x and y implicitly. Push x again
        % STACK: x, y, x
:       % Range from 1 to x
        % STACK: x, y, [1, 2, ..., x]
w       % Swap
        % STACK: x, [1, 2, ..., x], y
^       % Power, element-wise
        % STACK: x, [1^y,  2^y, ..., x^y]
w       % Swap
        % STACK: [1^y, 2^y, ..., x^y], x
\       % Modulo, element-wise
        % STACK: [mod(1^y,x), mod(2^y,x), ..., mod(x^y,x)]
        % A 0 at the k-th entry indicates that x^y is divisible by x. The last entry
        % is guaranteed to be 0
&X<     % Arg min: get (1-based) index of the first minimum (the first zero), say n
        % STACK: n
        % Implicitly display
```

Comment: Stack manipulation much.

Comment: Yep. I suspect Jelly will have a big advantage here, since it avoids all those "copy" and "swap"

Comment: Don't you have `find`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, `f`, but that finds all nonzero indices. So it would have to be `~f1)`:  negatve, find, get the first entry

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Many thanks to Leaky Nun for his many suggestions. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OylS4pmA4oG_4pmAJTBAw611&input=MgoyNQ)

```
;)R♀ⁿ♀%0@íu
```

Original 12-byte approach. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MVdY4pSCMeKVluKVnOKBvyVXWOKVnA&input=MjUKMg)

```
1WX│1╖╜ⁿ%WX╜
```

Another 12-byte approach. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=d-KUrGkp4pmAL-KZgktA4pmA4oG_z4A&input=MgoyNQ)

```
w┬i)♀/♂K@♀ⁿπ
```

A 13-byte approach. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=a-KVlzJg4pWcaWHigb8lWWDilZNO&input=MjUKMg)

```
k╗2`╜iaⁿ%Y`╓N
```

**Ungolfing:**

First algorithm

```
       Implicitly pushes y, then x.
;      Duplicate x.
)      Rotate duplicate x to bottom of the stack.
R      Range [1, x] (inclusive).
♀ⁿ     Map a**y over the range.
♀%     Map a**y%x over the range.
0@í    new_list.index(0)
u      Increment and print implicitly at the end of the program.
```

Original algorithm

```
       Implicitly pushes x, then y.
1WX    Pushes a truthy value to be immediately discarded 
         (in future loops, we discard a**y%x)
|      Duplicates entire stack.
         Stack: [y x y x]
1╖     Increment register 0.
╜      Push register 0. Call it a.
ⁿ      Take a to the y-th power.
%      Take a**y mod x.
W      If a**y%x == 0, end loop.
X      Discard the modulus.
╜      Push register 0 as output.
```

Third algorithm

```
       Implicitly pushes y, then x.
w      Pushes the full prime factorization of x.
┬      Transposes the factorization (separating primes from exponents)
i      Flatten (into two separate lists of primes and exponents).
)      Rotate primes to the bottom of the stack.
♀/     Map divide over the exponents.
♂K     Map ceil() over all of the divided exponents.
@      Swap primes and modified exponents.
♀ⁿ     Map each prime ** each exponent.
π      Product of that list. Print implicitly at the end of the program.
```

Fourth algorithm

```
     Implicitly pushes x, then y.
k╗   Turns stack [x y] into a list [x, y] and saves to register 0.
2    Pushes 2.
  `    Starts function with a.
  ╜i   Pushes register 0 and flattens. Stack: [x y a]
  a    Inverts the stack. Stack: [a y x]
  ⁿ%   Gets a**y%x.
  Y    Logical negate (if a**y is divisible by x, then 1, else 0)
  `    End function.
╓    Push first (2) values where f(x) is truthy, starting with f(0).
N    As f(0) is always truthy, get the second value.
     Print implicitly at the end of the program.
```

Comment: @LeakyNun Waiting for one of your winning golf suggestions :D

Comment: @LeakyNun I'd be happy to post those approaches, too, unless you want to post them yourself.

Comment: +1 for the smirk `;)`

Answer (score 2):

## dc, <del>23</del> 22 bytes

*Thanks to Delioth for his tip about input methods, saving a byte*

```
sysxz[zdlylx|0<F]dsFxp
```

Uses the stack depth operator `z` for incrementing the test case directly on the stack, and the modular exponentiation operator `|` for, well, modular exponentiation. Repeat testing until remainder is not greater than zero.

Comment: You technically don't need the `?` at the beginning, as a standard way to invoke some things is `> echo "x y [program]"|dc`, where `x` and `y` are the same as the Question- x and y will be dropped onto the stack as normal.

Comment: @Delioth Interesting, thanks! I always just used the `-e` option, but I'll use that from now on.

Comment: @Delioth, for me, using quotes throws errors reminding me that `"` is not implemented in `dc`, while not using quotes obviously gives shell errors. Is there anything to be done about this? I know `stderr` can be ignored, but it still bothers me.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>61 bytes</s>, <s>39 bytes</s>, <s>37 bytes</s>, 34 bytes

I'm still a newbie in R programming and it turns out this is my first function I create in R (**Yay!**) so I believe there's still room for improvement.

```
function(x,y){for(n in 2:x){if(n^y%%x==0){cat(x,y,n);break}}}
```

Online test can be conducted here: [RStudio on rollApp](https://www.rollapp.com/app/rstudio).

---

**Major progress:**

```
function(x,y){which.max((1:x)^y%%x==0)}
```

`which.max` works because it returns the highest value in a vector and if there are multiple it will return the first. In this case, we have a vector of many FALSEs (which are 0s) and a few TRUEs (which are 1s), so it will return the first TRUE.

---

**Another progress:**

```
function(x,y)which.max((1:x)^y%%x==0)
```

Finally, it beats out the answer using Python by two bytes. **:)**

**Another progress: (Again!)**

```
function(x,y)which.min((1:x)^y%%x)
```

---

Many thanks to [Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341440/axeman) and [user5957401](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58162/user5957401) for the help.

Comment: I think that your test link is dead.

Comment: @TheBikingViking Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit it after having my late lunch

Comment: if you use `which.min`, you could get rid of the `==0`. The modulus will return a number, which be no lower than 0.

Comment: @user5957401 Edited.Bolshoe spasibo...

Comment: For the same length of 34 bytes you also had the similar `function(x,y)which(!(1:x)^y%%x)[1]`.

Comment: Post it as an answer then @plannapus :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), 8 bytes

```
Lsm¹%0k>
```

**Explanation**

```
L         # range(1,x) inclusive
 sm       # each to the power of y
   ¹%     # each mod x
     0k   # find first index of 0 (0-based)
       >  # increment to 1-based
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=THNtwrklMGs-&input=OTYKMg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>26</s>  25 bytes

```perl6
{first * **$^y%%$^x,1..$x}
{first * **$^y%%$^x,1..*}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# bare block with two placeholder parameters ｢$^y｣ and ｢$^x｣
{
  # find the first value
  first

  # where when it ｢*｣ is taken to the power
  # of the outer blocks first parameter ｢$^y｣
  * ** $^y
  # is divisible by the outer blocks second parameter ｢$^x｣
  %% $^x,

  # out of the values from 1 to Inf
  1 .. *
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

```
(i=1;While[n=i++;Mod[n^#2,#]!=0];n)&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 11 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Translation of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90577/43319).

```apl
0⍳⍨⊣|(⍳⊣)*⊢
```

`0⍳⍨` find the first zero in
`⊣|` the division remainders when *x* divides
`(⍳⊣)*` the integers one through *x*, raised to the power of
`⊢` *y*

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u21900%u2373%u2368%u22A3%7C%28%u2373%u22A3%29*%u22A2%20%u22C4%20f/%A8%2826%202%29%2896%202%29%2832%203%29%2864%209%29%2827%203%29&run)

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 48 bytes

```
param($x,$y)(1..$x|?{!(("$_*"*$y+1|iex)%$x)})[0]
```

Takes input `$x` and `$y`. Constructs a range from `1` to `$x`, then uses `Where-Object` to filter those numbers. The filter takes the string `"$_*"` (i.e., the current number with an asterisk) and uses string-multiplication to concatenate those `$y` times, then tacks on a final `1` at the end, then pipes that to `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`). This takes the place of `[math]::Pow($_,$y)`, since PowerShell doesn't have an exponentiation operator, and is two bytes shorter. That's fed into the modulo operator `%` with `$x` -- thus, if it's divisible, this will be `0`, so we encapsulate that in parens and take the Boolean-not `!(...)` thereof. Thus, if its divisible, it'll be included by this filter, and all other numbers will be excluded.

Finally, we encapsulate the resultant numbers in parens `(...)` and take the `[0]` index. Since the range entered sorted `1..$x`, this will be the smallest. That's left on the pipeline and printing is implicit.

#### Test cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> (26,2),(96,2),(32,3),(64,9),(27,3)|%{($_-join', ')+' -> '+(.\smallest-positive-number-divisor.ps1 $_[0] $_[1])}
26, 2 -> 26
96, 2 -> 24
32, 3 -> 4
64, 9 -> 2
27, 3 -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <s>55</s> 33 bytes

```
$i=1;while($i**$y%$x)$i++;echo$i;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

Includes +3 for `-p` (not +1 since the code contains `'`)

Run with the input on STDIN

```
power.pl <<< "96 2"
```

`power.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
/ /;1while++$\**$'%$`}{
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
AQf!%^THG
```

A program that takes input of a list of the form `[x, y]` on STDIN and prints the result.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQf%21%25%5ETHG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B26%2C2%5D%0A%5B96%2C2%5D%0A%5B32%2C3%5D%0A%5B64%2C9%5D%0A%5B27%2C3%5D&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
AQf!%^THG  Program. Input: Q
AQ         G=Q[0];H=Q[1]
  f        First truthy input T in [1, 2, 3, ...] with function:
     ^TH    T^H
    %   G   %G
   !        Logical not (0 -> True, all other modulus results -> False)
           Implicitly print
```

Answer (score -1):

## PHP 59 bytes

Sorry, but I can't test this from my mobile. **:)**

```
function blahblah($x,$y){
  for($i=0;1;$i++){
    if(!$i^$y%$x){
      return $i;
    }
  }
}
```

Golfed

```
function b($x,$y){for($i=0;1;$i++){if(!$i^$y%$x)return $i;}
```

Comment: You're using $z where you should be using $x and I don't think you're incrementing $i in the loop